# Is this ring Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noetherian

> If $R=\{\frac m n\in{\mathbb{Q}}: \mbox{7 does not divide $n$}\}$. Is $R$ Noetherian?

What i think is the ideals of $R$ are finitely generated. But how do i prove this, i have no idea. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Hint: think R as the localization in $p = (7)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: every element is associate to a power of $7$.